# Complex View Animation in Android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

In my android application I want to show animation for view to pop out from its position

In more details i want to achieve something like this -

- On click of View ( This can be any type of View say ImageView ) it will move towards top of the screen
- After certain distance it will again move to the center of the screen while little bit zooming-in

I know little bit about Animation class, Animation Listener and AnimationSet in android.
but still seeking for guideline to achieve this functionality

Could you please suggest way to achieve this?

Edited Part -

Main Problem is occuring in getting right coordinates of view after its movement to top
and next problem is bring that view to center of the screen from last position

Comment: I think you need a zoom in animation, is that what u want ?

Comment: I think only zoom will not work. I want set of animations in which view will move towards top and then move and settle at the center of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following code will have an animation - which will move down and come to middle with zoom effect

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
        TranslateAnimation translateAnimation1 = new TranslateAnimation(
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,
                0.0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,
                0.8f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,
                0.0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,
                0.8f);
        translateAnimation1.setDuration(1000);
        translateAnimation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {}
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {}
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                TranslateAnimation translateAnimation2 = new TranslateAnimation(
                        TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,
                        0.8f,
                        TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,
                        0.5f,
                        TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,
                        0.8f,
                        TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,
                        0.5f);
                translateAnimation2.setDuration(1000);
                AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(false);
                ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 2.0f,1.0f,2.0f,ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF ,0.5f,ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
                scaleAnimation.setDuration(1000);
                animationSet.addAnimation(scaleAnimation);
                animationSet.addAnimation(translateAnimation2);
                view.startAnimation(animationSet);

            }
        });
        view.startAnimation(translateAnimation1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
ScaleAnimation animScale = new ScaleAnimation(0, 2, 0, 5);
animScale.setDuration(2000);
AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false);
animation.addAnimation(animScale);
view.startAnimation(animation);
```

Change the values in ScaleAnimation's constructor to get ur required output

Comment: Hello Hardik, Thanx for prompt reply .. code you have given is working great for zooming view .. but please have look at Edited Part of the post .. so that you will get more idea about problem ..

Comment: Look the above answer given by Sudar works fine, this must be wat u wanted.